# Is python list a continuous memory allocation like array or a linked list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Does python allocate memory in a continuous fashion in memory while implementing list or use a dynamic allocation?

If continuous, how does it append new elements? It should cause problems in implementing a large list.

How does this actually work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is implemented behind the hood, but as it is accessible by index it doesn't look like a linked list. To me, it looks like a vector of pointers/references, but I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Hey, I found this amazing post http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/ and I got cleared about it. Hope it helps you too.